# SOLVED How do I query with HttpClient containing Turkish characters

Tags: c#, encoding, httpclient

I'm developing a web service with C# . The client works fine, but if the parameter contains Turkish characters, the result is null.
I know this is an encoding problem but I don't know how to set it.

I tried the following for HttpClient:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("windows-1254"));
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("tr-TR"));
```

but it didn't work. I thought maybe if I encode the Turkish characters in the parameter, in turn I've tried:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(district);
Uri.EscapeUriString(district);
Uri.EscapeDataString(district);
```

but it didn't work again. My code block below:

```
private HttpClient getClient() {
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServiceBaseUrl"]);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("windows-1254"));
    return httpClient;
}

public SupportPersonDto GetSupportPersonList(string city, string district) {
    SupportPersonDto serviceResult = null;
    string param = "<head>" +
                        "<user>" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceUser"] + "</user>" +
                        "<pwd>" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servicePass"] + "</pwd>" +
                        "<city>" + city + "</city>" +
                        "<district>" + district  + "</district>" +
                   "</head>";

    HttpClient httpClient = getClient();
    string apiUrl = "?xmlData=" + param;

    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
        var stream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        stream.Wait();

        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "NGDIRECTORY";
        xRoot.IsNullable = true;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SupportPersonDto), xRoot);
        serviceResult = (SupportPersonDto)serializer.Deserialize(stream.Result);
    }
    httpClient.Dispose();
    return serviceResult;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: which parameter?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're 100% sure that you haven't gotten anything strange in those parameters? I ask because you're building XML manually, which is always a sign of broken code.

Comment: @DanielA.White district parameter.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I know that creating manual xml is not a good method, but I was asked to do it that way. 
no problem if the district parameter is BORNOVA, but if it is KARŞIYAKA, the result is null

Comment: perhaps you need to do some url escaping.

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about what **accept**encoding does? It tells the server what kind of encoding you accept in the response, you need to set the `Content-Type` header to tell the server how you encoded the content you post to it. All you've said now is that you accept a Turkish response, but you haven't said what you sent the server. A typical value for what you're sending would probably be `Content-Type: application/xml; charset=windows-1254`

Comment: Never mind, you're passing it via the url. You need to encode the xml properly, try `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(...)`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for reply but encode does not work. I'm trying to set Content-Type header

Comment: Content-Type won't have an impact on url data. Have you debugged the server, to see what it gets in the data from your request?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the **server** supports non-ASCII content?

Comment: @IanKemp yes i am sure

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i cant debug on the server, and server administrators certainly does not help in this regard :(

Comment: So you aren't able to reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , No, the problem continues in local. Strange thing, if I call url with chrome (in local), I have a Turkish character problem and the result is null. Similarly, the result returns null in postman. But if I call url with Internet Explorer it works normally and the data returns.
I applied the same header information sent to Internet Explorer to postman. The result has not changed, again null. On the IE's Network tab, I noticed that the Turkish character parameters have changed. For example IE changed İZMİR to Ä°ZMÄ°R

I'm still working on the problem

Comment: Did you or did you not encode the url data? It is not safe to pass turkish accents and the likes unencoded.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen , I tried both methods, neither of them worked. I did not succeed with postman too. I keep trying

Comment: Can you post one of the urls you tried? You can mask out the hostname if that is sensitive, but please try to get the actual data you posted. If needs be, try to construct a set of dummy data that fails the same way that you can safely post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to everyone who helped.
Both Daniel and Lasse suggested me to use UrlEncode, which is the correct answer.
The problem was solved editing the code as follows:

```
district = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(district, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
```

after so many days :)

Thank you again for your help